# Writing an extremely basic mex function in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to to write a very simple mex file, let's say just to try out the way it works. I have gone through a lot of materials and more I read, more I get confused. I need this to further write a mex file that interacts with external hardware. Please help!

```
// header file - printing.h //

#include<iostream>
class printing
{
public:

    void name();
    void age();
};

// cpp file - printing.cpp //
#include<iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "printing.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray*plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
   printing p1;
   p1.name();
   p1.age();

}

void printing::name()
{
    cout << "NAME" << endl;
}

void printing::age()
{
    cout << "20" << endl;

}
```

// .m file - test.m //

```
sprintf ('WELCOME')
printing()
```

When i run the test.m file, I would like to see
WELCOME
NAME
20
However I see only welcome. I understand that I have not updated the plhs[] array. But all I want to do is execute something inside mexFunction.Why wouldn't the cout inside name() and age() achieve this?

Also, how do i confirm that name() and age() are executed?

Comment: Note that cout is linked to the system's console and that Matlab has an own "console" which they call the "command window". This means your cout output will not be seen in Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `cout` will not print to the MATLAB console, you need to use the MEX printf function.

```
mexPrintf("NAME\n");
```